# Windows Forms C# picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть форма, например 600 на 800. В этой форме есть picturebox 200 на 220. Картинка, которая будет загружаться в этот picturebox, будет превышать кол-во пикселей, например 400 на 400. Как сделать чтобы вся картинка уместилась полностью в picturebox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

> Изображение внутри PictureBox растягивается или сжимается, чтобы
>   соответствовать размеру PictureBox.

или

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

> Размер изображения увеличивается или уменьшается с сохранением
>   соотношения размеров.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Поясните як это работает

Comment: А, всё, понял. Спасибо! pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage; - подходит.